# get attachment id from redemption or RDO MAil

Tags: outlook, c#-3.0, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm developping an outlook addIn using C# and I need  to get attachment id from redemption or RDO MAil.
how's that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to replace attachment with a  link  in async callback method and I needed to detect which attachment to replace.
I used as flag the contentID of the Interop.Redemption.RDOAttachment Object and it worked fine, Thank you .

Comment: Keep in mind that contentID is not guaranteed to be present on an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook attachments (unlike messages) do not have unique ids since they only exist in the context of their parent messages.

`PR_ATTACH_NUM` property is used to open attachments - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc841969.aspx.

But that property is not guaranteed to stay the same when a message is opened. More than that, the value of the `PR_ATTACH_NUM` property can differ depending on whether you retrieve it from the attachment table or from the attachment itself. Below is example from [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/) (I am its author):

What exactly are you trying to do?

[image]

Comment: Dmitry, a follow up question - is there any way to identify an attachment after reopening the message a second time? I'm currently using the attachment number, but if this is not guaranteed - is there a stable way?

Comment: file name would probably work in most cases, but it is not guaranteed to be unique for any given message.